# No Such Table issue

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite, fmdb

I've included the database in my project and also I've used fmdb before. I tried to copy my code from my old project but still it says "No such table"

Here is the console log:

```
DB Error: 1 "no such table: ANIMALS"
DB Query: SELECT * FROM ANIMALS WHERE Name = 'koyun' 
DB Path: (null)
```

and here is my code:

```
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"HayvanlarM" ofType:@"sqlite"];

    FMDatabase *database = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:path];

    [database setLogsErrors:TRUE];

    [database open];

    NSString *anQuery = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM ANIMALS WHERE Name = '%@' ",[[bBackG objectAtIndex:0]stringByDeletingPathExtension]];

    FMResultSet *results = [database executeQuery:anQuery];


    while([results next]) {

        NSString *animalName = [results stringForColumn:@"TR"];

        //gjText.text = animalName;
        NSLog(@"animalName: %@",animalName);
    }



    [database close];
    database = nil;
```

I tried to create my db through firefox sqlite manager and I tried lita, but both gave me same error `( no such table )`

Could anyone tell me what's the problem in my code? I tried all solutions posted about such problem and none of them worked with me so far.

Comment: Can you confirm that the path being returned is valid?  The default behavior for SQLite when a database is not found is to create a new empty one, and since it is empty it won't find the table you are looking for.

Comment: when i was including db in Xcode , i wasn't choosing to add it to target, after i choose to add it to app target , it started to read from database 

thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure while you are accessing existing database that physical database type and database type in code must match.
 like `.sqlite` or `.db`

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Database", ofType:"db")
```

Answer (score 1):

when i was including db in Xcode , i wasn't choosing to add it to target, after i choose to add it to app target , it started to read from database thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved a analogous problem by delete the app in simulator and rebulid the proj.
I think the app's DB was not the one which I have modified.so clean the app in simulator x-code will copy the newest DB.